# Regarding with list and insert getting stuck

Tags: python

```
my = [1,2]
for v in range(2):  
    my.insert(-1,my[v])
print(my)
```

Answer is:  `[1, 1, 1, 2]`

I am not able to understand the answer. If anyone could explain it would be helpful.

Comment: Did you expect a different result? Which one? Why?

Comment: then how come there are three 1s?

Comment: Because in the first iteration 1 is inserted, and in the second iteration 1 is inserted again.

Comment: i thought the result should be [1,2,0,1] , I was considering the range value also

Comment: You insert `my[0] = 1` at the second to last index, so `my = [1, 1, 2]`. Then, you insert `my[1] = 1` at the second to last index, so `my = [1, 1, 1, 2]`.

Comment: Where should a 0 come from?

Comment: @ALEXANDERABRAHAM To achieve `my = [1, 2, 0, 1]`, you could use `my.append(v)`.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop `for v in range(2):` provides the sequence of 0 and 1 values in `v`.
The list `my` has the value 1 in position 0 and value 2 in position 1.

In the first iteration of the loop, the line `my.insert(-1,my[v])` puts the value for v equals 0, that is `my[0] == 1`, in the position -1.
After that, the list `my` will have the values `[1, 1, 2]`.
Then, the first and the second positions of `my` will have 1's.

In the second iteration of the loop, the line `my.insert(-1,my[v])` puts the value for v equals 1, that is `my[1] == 1` (since now `my` has the values `[1, 1, 2]`), in the position -1. Then, the final content of `my` is `[1, 1, 1, 2]`.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation , now able to understand. people like you is a great help for beginner. once again thanks

Comment: Actually I had one more doubt with these code

my = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for v in range(2):  
    my.insert(-1,my[v])  
print(my)

Comment: Actually I had one more doubt with these code

my = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for v in range(2):  
    my.insert(-1,my[v])  
print(my)

#The answer for these is: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 10]
#
#In these the doubt was in the second last place how 2 came ???
#I thought 1 should come in that place
#my thought regarding output would be  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 1, 10]

Comment: Consider the list `my = [7, 8, 9]`. The value in `my[-1]` is 9. In other words, the position -1 is the last position. When we use `insert` instead `append`, we determine where the new value will be inserted. So, the code `my.insert(-1, 42)` will insert the value 42 in the currently last position (index 2), moving the value 9 to position 3.

Comment: I understood my doubt how its working thanks